# how to handle empty array for text widget in build method?

Tags: flutter

How would I handle the `objectA[0].name` (a string) in the build method if the `array` is empty?

```
Text(objectB.objectC.objectA[0].name),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a great way to do this inline but with a simple extension method to return the original `null` or the `iterable` depending on whether the item is `null` or empty you can make it work.

### First

#### Extension Method

(requires dart v2.7 - update in your `pubspec.yaml` file)

```dart
extension IterableExtension<T> on Iterable<T> {
  Iterable<T> get nullWhenEmpty =>
      this == null || this.isEmpty ? null : this;
}
```

### Second

To handle `null` values while you're traversing an object you can use the Dart's `conditional member access` operator (`?.`). This operator will only continue with the right-hand side if the left-hand side of the operator is not `null`. Use the `elementAt` method on a an `iterable` to be able to use the `?.` operator in the chain. Then, use the `?.` operations with the `if null` operator (`??`) to get your default value.

### Solution

```dart
final String value = objectB?.objectC?.objectA?.nullWhenEmpty?.elementAt(0)?.name;

Text(value ?? 'Default Text');
```

You can, of course, inline the above code instead of using an additional variable.

Resources

- [Dart Language Tour: Other Operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#other-operators)
- [Dart Language Tour: Classes](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#classes)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the array is `objectC` you can do something like:

`Text(objectC.isEmpty? "" :objectC[0].name)`

You can read more about ternary operators in dart [here](https://alvinalexander.com/flutter/dart-ternary-operator-syntax-examples/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe checking if the list has an element, using `isNotEmpty`

```
child: (objectB.objectC.objectA.isNotEmpty) 
         ? Text(objectB.objectC.objectA[0].name) 
         : Container(),
```